# Loading a Vue file's content into a JavaScript variable for routing

Tags: import, routes, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I've been trying to use the vue-router package for days without figuring out how it works, and it kind of drives me crazy.

My problem: I want to make a Single Page Application using VueJS, and I have taken the vue-router package since it is the routing package officially supported by the VueJS development team.
I've read a lot of "getting started" articles, lots of them start by hard-writing the template like this:

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
```

But since I'm not really into writing my entire template between those two quotes marks, I searched for a way to write my template into a file, and then load the file's content into a JS variable.
It seems that it's possible to write the templates into .vue files, and then load them into variables using:

```
import App from './App.vue';
```

But when I do this that way I get this error: "Unexpected token import".

I'm really frustrated by that, haven't they thought about a really convenient way for the template loading to be compatible on every browser? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look into [Vue CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) for helping you set up a desired scaffold for your project. Based on the options you choose you can end up with a webpack backed template along with the vue-router included. Webpack will take care of bundling your project so you don't encounter errors like that one.

Generally what you want to do is use vue files. A vue file is divided into three parts, and would look something like this:

```
<template>
  // Your HTML for this component goes here
</template>

<script>
  // Your JS for this component goes here
</script>

<style>
  // Your CSS for this component goes here
</style>
```

Once you have your components organized like this, handling routing is pretty straightforward. You designate a file to contain the router object that handles the routing.

These are pretty much basics, so I won't go into details here but you can learn a lot more on the official Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) page. [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-vue-router) is also an example project that shows how to construct simple components in vue files and how to properly use the vue-router.